# Android proguard Ignore All Classes except of one

Tags: java, android, proguard

I need help with turning off all features and disable everything that Proguard do for all classes but one. One class should be obfuscated (contains security things). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

-dontshrink

-dontoptimize

-dontobfuscate

-keep,allowshrinking,allowoptimization,allowobfuscation class org.mypackage.MyClass

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It's not obfuscating my class. I'm using compileSdkVersion 29,
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2", Android Studio 3.5.2. R8 is now the engine for obfuscating and shrinking.

Answer (score -3):

```
Use this Line into the proguard 
Enter all package name for disable things of proguard


 -dontwarn your_package_name.**
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? I think that just makes Proguard ignore all of the warnings that the packages may provide.

Comment: yse add this in proguard.cfg and all warning is going off

Comment: ... which is not what the OP was asking to do.